# running python command through ssh

Tags: python, ssh

I am using SSH secure shell to connect to the my remote server. I am using plone. When I go to the console through

```
./bin/instance debug
```

I am able to execute python codes. However, when I write

```
python bootstrap.py
```

it gives me error that says:

> python:command not found.

I think it is due to the path issue. But, I don't have any idea to solve it! Can anyone suggest me about what should I do?

Comment: Try an absolute path, like `/usr/bin/python`.

Comment: Has nothing to do with Plone

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should use something like that:

`ssh <your_server> "/usr/bin/python <path_of_your_project>/bin/instance debug"`

Where `<your_server>` is the IP or hostname of your server and `<path_of_your_project>` the fullpath of your project.

Answer (score 2):

This means that there is no python executable on the system path for the user account you are using to ssh into the server. However, as you are able to run bin/instance debug, there must be a python executable on the server somewhere.

As poke has suggested, you can use an absolute path to that python executable, you just need to figure out where it is located. You will find that if you read the first line of you bin/instance script the path to the python it uses is right there.

```
$ more bin/instance
#!/usr/bin/python
...
```